# How to optimize id and limit query for huge data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a billion rows in mysql table and I want to query the table with an indexed field lets say timestamp.

I want to query last 7 days data which can be 1000000 rows approximately and I am querying based on last id fetched and a limit which is 500.

This query works fine when I am processing upto 5000000 rows of data which is 10000 queries but when I increase the number of queries to, let's say, 50000, I can see a degradation in performance over time. Query used to take 5-10ms in the starting but after running for a long time it degraded to 2s. How can I optimize this ?

I earlier tried a naive solution which is limit, offset which gave highly unoptimized results so I tried to optimized it by saving last id and adding last id while querying every time but then again performance degraded overtime for this if I keep fetching one after another for 3-4 hours.

JAVA : Using Hibernate and Slicing

```
Date date = new Date();
Date timestamp = new DateTime(date).minusDays(7).toDate();

while (true) {
    Integer rowLimit = 500;
    Sort.Order sortingOrder = Sort.Order.asc("timestamp");
    Sort sort = Sort.by(sortingOrder);

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, rowLimit, sort);

    long queryStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    entityDataSlice = repository.findAllByTimestampAfterAndIdGreaterThan(
          timestamp, lastId, pageable
    );

    long queryEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (!entityDataSlice.hasNext()) {
          break;
    }
}
```

MYSQL :

```
select *  
 from table 
where timestamp >= "some_time" 
  and id >= <some_id> 
order 
   by timestamp 
limit 500
```

Expected result was a performance optimization but overtime it degraded.

Expected upto 100ms overtime but its actually upto 2-3 secs which is more likely to be degraded further upto 5-10 secs

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Meanwhile, if you have `INDEX(timestamp)` you don't need the `and id...`.  In fact, it may get in the way of optimizing the `ORDER BY`.

So, if your query is this:

```
select  *
    from  table
    where  timestamp >= "some_time"
    order by  timestamp
    limit  500
```

*and* you have `INDEX(timestamp)`, then it is well optimized, and it will not slow down (aside from caching issues).

If that is just a simplified version of the 'real' query, the all bets are off.